# If statement condition problem javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, comparison-operators

I have an object containing quotes.
I want my code to print only 5 quotes but the if statement is skipped (I think), and it keeps on printing quotes until it ends. I want to know where the problem is.
Maybe it's in the if statement or comparison or condition or variable scope.
I've tried every possible way to compare `i` and `r` but it's simply not working.
I'm just starting out with js. Any help is appreciated.

```js
let i = 0;
let r = 3; 

function printQuote() {
  
  item = data.notes[i];// data is my object having 15 quotes
  
  $('.quote-content').html(item.quote); 
  $('.quote-book').html(item.title);
  $('.quote-author').html(item.author);

  i+=1;
}

document.getElementById('next_button').innerHTML = 'Next Quote';

function getQuote() {
  var $button = $('.next');

  printQuote();
  
  if(parseInt(i,10)>parseInt(r,10)){
    window.alert('No more Quotes to show.');
    $button.disabled = True;
  }
  else{  
    $button.on('click', printQuote);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  getQuote();
});
```

List item

Comment: Your 'i' and 'r' variables are Numbers. Why do you use parseInt()?

Comment: I thought there was problem with parsing integers but now I know what the problem was. refer to below answers. now I removed parseInt().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `getQuote` method is only called once when the document is ready. After that, only the `printQuote` method is called when your button is clicked since that's the listener you attached. So when you click the button, the quote data is set and `i` is incremented by one - that's all. I assume you'd want to move your `i` and `r` comparison logic to inside `printQuote` or have the `getQuote` method called when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is not working because those i and r variables is not updated in your `getQuote` function.

You can use this instead:

```js
let i = 0;
let r = 3;

let data = {
  notes: [
    {
      quote:
        '1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet illo voluptatum cupiditate asperiores quod a aperiam itaque nesciunt odio quam esse aliquid, ab praesentium sapiente mollitia. Fugit officia quidem odio blanditiis voluptatum aliquam error expedita modi commodi quod. Nobis est consequatur odit maiores possimus! Alias ullam quae facere fuga unde?',
        title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
        author: 'Lorem, ipsum.'
    },
    {
      quote: '2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, omnis.',
      title: 'Lorem, ipsum dolor.',
      author: 'Lorem, ipsum.'
    },
    {
      quote: '3) Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.',
      title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
      author: 'Lorem, ipsum.'
    },
    {
      quote: '4) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, omnis.',
      title: 'Lorem, ipsum dolor.',
      author: 'Lorem, ipsum.'
    },
    {
      quote: '5) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, omnis.',
      title: 'Lorem, ipsum dolor.',
      author: 'Lorem, ipsum.'
    },
  ],
};

function printQuote() {
  item = data.notes[i]; // data is my object having 15 quotes

  if (parseInt(i, 10) > parseInt(r, 10)) {
    window.alert('No more Quotes to show.');
    $('#next_button').prop('disabled', true);
  }

  $('.quote-content').html(item.quote);
  $('.quote-book').html(item.title);
  $('.quote-author').html(item.author);

  i += 1;
}

document.getElementById('next_button').innerHTML = 'Next Quote';

function getQuote() {
  var $button = $('#next_button');

  printQuote();
  $button.on('click', printQuote);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  getQuote();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Quote Test</title>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <div class="quote-content"></div>
    <div class="quote-book"></div>
    <div class="quote-author"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="next_button"></button>
  </div>

  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked for me but those two variables are global so why did'nt they got updated in getQuote()?

Comment: Because when DOM loads, your `getQuote` function only called once. But your `printQuote` is called whenever the button is clicked. So your conditional statement is working for the first time when DOM loads your scripts. You have to move your condition in the `printQuote` function so that your conditions runs whenever the button is clicked.